# Sending file contents to another command bash

Tags: bash

I have a plain text file with two columns.  I need to take each line which contains two columns and send them to a command.

The source file looks like this:

potato potato2

the line needs to be sent to another command so it looks like this

command potato potato2

output I can just have to std out.

Been such a long time that I've tried a simple bash script...

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your file contains two columns per line, separated by either spaces or tabs.

```
xargs -n 2 command < file.txt
```

---

See: `man xargs`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to read a file line by line, so the following code should do:

```
while read -r line
do 
    echo "$line" | xargs your-other-command #Use xargs to convert input into arguments 
done < source-file.txt
```